# Массив в массиве в массиве

Tags: c#, массивы

Задачка реализовать массив трехуровневой вложенности. Структура вот такая:

```
[1]
   [1,2]
   [45,213]
   [452,123]
   [2,3]
[2]
   [4,1]
   [23,2]
```

Чем-то напоминает JSON. Как реализовать такой массив? Какой тип данных лучше использовать - Dictionary, HashMap и т.д.

Answer (score 5):

Тут даже выдумывать особо ничего не надо. Воспользуйтесь обычными средствами работы с массивами. Так называемый jagged-array:

```
var arr = new[]
       {
           new [] 
           {
               new[] { 1,   2 },
               new[] { 45,  213 },
               new[] { 452, 123 },
               new[] { 2,3 },
           }, 
           new []
           {
               new []{ 4, 1},
               new []{ 32, 2 },
           }
       };
```

Answer (score 3):

Не очень понял, где тут трехуровневая вложенность. По тому, что написано, похоже на обычный массив массивов.

Если известно, что первый индекс нумеруется от нуля до какого-то конечного числа, то используйте `List<List<int>> array;`

Если первым индексом может быть вообще любое число, то используйте `Dictionary<int, List<int>> array;`

Доступ в обоих случаях будет осуществляться так: `array[index1][index2]`;